# What interesting 3-player strategy games are available?

Tags: recommendations

In my apartment there tend to be 3 of us wanting to play board games regularly, and we're fond of strategy games. Unfortunately, 3 is not the optimal number for most of the more interesting ones that we've come across.

We're familiar with Carcassone, Cataan, and Forbidden Island, but we've been wondering if there are games that are more towards the Quorridor, Blokkus, etc style of game that are somewhat quicker to play and where moving and/or placing pieces is the main part of the game. And, for that matter, if there are games like this that explicitly work optimally with 3 people (We've tried 3 person Blokkus and it's messy).

Comment: Hello RSid, and welcome to the site!  I'm voting to close this question, as we've taken a recent policy decision against recommendation questions of this kind.  (For reasons why, see [this meta discussion](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/656/245)).  If you take this one over to the site chat, you should hopefully find that people are glad to work with you to understand exactly what kind of games your group prefers, and recommend some.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Seeing the recommendation tag/rec questions I assumed they were in.

Comment: They used to be in on a we-hadn't-decided-yet basis (hence the tag), but we ended up finding we almost-always closed them.  So now it's official policy.  (You raise a good point here; we should do something about the tag.  I'll go edit the tag wiki in the meantime...)

Comment: For a game like Blokus that's good with three players, I'd recommend Blokus Trigon.  The BoardGameGeek community even goes as far as to say it's best played with three: http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/21550/blokus-trigon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really, really recommend [Ticket to Ride: Nordic Countries](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/31627/ticket-to-ride-nordic-countries) as an interesting and balanced three player game. Its unique selling point, over the other Ticket to Ride games, is that it is specifically designed for three! You can play a two-player variant, but you can't for four or more. So you're *genuinely* getting a game that works best for three.

The other game that is universally acclaimed to be amazing, and is very good for different number of players, is [Agricola](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/31260/agricola).  Agricola gives you a different initial board layout for three players, and has many Occupation cards that are specially designed for 3+ players (in addition to the standard ones for 1+ players, and some for 4+ players).  You really feel like the designer paid lots of care and attention to making sure the game would work amazingly for 2 and 3 player games, as well as for larger groups.  (And indeed there's even a serviceable solitaire option!)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Samurai](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3/samurai). To be honest I haven't played it all that much yet (~10 games) but it feels like a game that's easy to learn but has depth in it. It plays best with 3 or 4 players. You can play it in a few different ways: with random placement, random tiles or chosen by players.

Answer (score 2):

If by 'like Blokkus' you mean an abstract, then I recommend [Talat](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/39406/talat).  A game of balancing focus between two opponents.  I've only been able to play it a handful of times, but have enjoyed it more every time.

Another quick recommendation if you want to play something with a variety of player (3 player included) would be [7 Wonders](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/68448/7-wonders).  I love playing this game.  One thing that I continually enjoy about it is how differently it plays with different numbers of players.  The 2 player variant creates the most strategic game, while 3 players uses the normal game rules, but creates a big game of risk when deciding which cards to pass (since you will see each hand more than once).  Always ready to recommend 7 Wonders.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [San Marco](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1041/san-marco) - it's an older title but it is one of the best puzzle-ish "euro-style" games with three players (not as good with four).